# Design for my models in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a Game model which uses a foreign key Moves like so:

```
class Moves(models.Model):
   player1 = []
   player2 = []

   def make_move(self, a_int, b_int, c_bool):        
    if c_bool:
        self.player1.append(a_int)
    else:
        self.player2.append(b_int)

   #...irrelevant functions

class Game(models.Model):
   #...irrelevant variables
   moves = models.ForeignKey(Moves)
```

So I want for each game to have a UNIQUE set of Moves. Moves are stored in the list of player1 and player2.

So in my tests I do something like this...

```
class MakeMoveTestCase(TestCase):    
    def test_make_move(self):
        g = Game()
        g.moves.make_move(3, 0, False) #####throws error here
        g.moves.make_move(4, 0, False)
```

and get this error:

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'

I need help getting rid of this error. Also, if you have a better design I would like to see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of showing you how to get rid of this error, I will try to explain what is wrong with your design.

First, the `Moves` class, as you defined it, does not make sense as a model. This is because there are no model fields defined there. If you want to store data with this model, you have to define attributes which are instances of [field classes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#field-types).

So you would probably want to rename `Moves` to `Move` (as it represents a single move) and redefine it as follows:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _

class Move(models.Model):
    PLAYER_1, PLAYER_2 = 1, 2
    PLAYERS = (
        (PLAYER_1, _('Player 1')),
        (PLAYER_2, _('Player 2'))
    )

    game = models.ForeignKey(Game, related_name='moves')
    player = models.IntegerField(choices=PLAYERS)
    x = models.IntegerField()
    y = models.IntegerField()
```

Now, if you want to create a game and a move and add it to the game then you could write something like this:

```
game = Game.objects.create(...)
move = Move.objects.create(game=game, x=1, y=5, player=Move.PLAYER_2)
```

Comment: the move represents a Point namedtuple that I have created. so something like this. `[Point(x=4, y=0), Point(x=4, y=1), Point(x=4, y=2), Point(x=4, y=3)]` for player1 and etc.

Comment: I know I was creating a model without field classes, hence I was suspicious of my design. How could I make it better?

Comment: I see what you are saying, but how would I handle it for 2 players?

Comment: So each move belongs to a given player, right? And each move is basically a list of points, yes?

Comment: yes each move belongs to a player. But each move is only ONE point. I was just storing it as a list.

Answer (score 2):

If you're implementing in Django, and you want to keep a good model-view-template distinction, then you should consider changes to your `Moves` model. Models should only represent data and therefore `make_move` should be moved to a view or some other support class. The players in your `Moves` model also seems like it should be a separate class since a player could theoretically have moves in multiple games, etc. In other words, decouple the players from the moves.

Also, I agree with @piotrekw, that `Moves` should become `Move` and should only represent a single move. Each move should link to the `Player` who made it as a foreign key field, and also to the `Game` it belongs to.

```
class Player(models.Model):
  pass

class Game(models.Model):
  player1 = models.ForeignKeyField(Player._id)

class Move(models.Model):
  game = models.ForeignKeyField(Game._id)
  player = models.ForeignKeyField(Player._id)
  a_int = models.IntegerField()
  b_int = models.IntegerField()
```

From here, actually adding a `Move` should follow standard Django practice you can find in the tutorial [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial01/).

Answer (score 1):

You should create Moves instance in your test before Game instance and link it to game before call it's method:

```
class MakeMoveTestCase(TestCase):    
    def test_make_move(self):
        moves = Moves()
        game = Game(moves=moves)
```